# Preserve order of JSON data when inserting into SQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, json

I have multiple input fields that I serialize with jquery and then saves the data to my SQL database with a AJAX call. When I serialize the input fields, the order of the serialized JSON data looks like this:

```
[{
  "value1": [ "123", "111", "222", "333" ],
  "value2": [ "111", "222", "333", "444" ],
  "value3": [ "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444" ],
  "title1": [ "This is a title" ],
  "title2": [ "Another title" ]
}]
```

Although I'd like it to be like this:

```
[
  { "value1": [ "123", "111", "222", "333" ] },
  { "title1": "This is a title" },
  { "value2": [ "111", "222", "333", "444" ] },
  { "title2": "Another title" },
  { "value3": [ "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444" ] }
]
```

The line that serializes the code looks like the following:

```
var inputVals = $(this).closest('.blockContent').find("select, textarea, input").serialize();
```

The PHP code that encodes the array to JSON format:

```
parse_str($request->inputVals,$inputVals);
$inputVals = array($inputVals);
$inputVals = json_encode($inputVals);
```

Example of input that gets serialized:

```
<input name="value1[0]" value="{{ $jsonValues['value1'][0] }}" type="number">
<input name="value1[1]" value="{{ $jsonValues['value1'][1] }}" type="number">
<input name="title1" value="{{ $jsonValues['value1'] }}" type="text">
```

**Update:**

To formulate my question in a better way, how can I from Jquery/javascript make the input fields above become like the JSON structure in a format that can be sorted like what I want in the JSON code above?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript (and therefore JSON) objects are unordered. There's literally no difference between

```
[{
  "value1": [ "123", "111", "222", "333" ],
  "title1": [ "This is a title" ],
  "value2": [ "111", "222", "333", "444" ],
  "title2": [ "Another title" ],
  "value3": [ "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444" ]
}]
```

and

```
[{
  "title1": [ "This is a title" ],
  "value2": [ "111", "222", "333", "444" ],
  "value3": [ "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444" ]
  "value1": [ "123", "111", "222", "333" ],
  "title2": [ "Another title" ],
}]
```

However, arrays *are* ordered. If you can change your data structure to something like

```
[{
  "value1": [ "123", "111", "222", "333" ],
  "title1": [ "This is a title" ]
}, {
  "value2": [ "111", "222", "333", "444" ],
  "title2": [ "Another title" ]
}, {
  "value3": [ "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444" ],
  "title3": "..."
}]
```

you'll find that the order is preserved. (Each object might have their `value` or `title` first, but each value and title will go together.)

Comment: yeah, that's what I understood but I'm struggling to get that structure with serialize(), any idea how I would redo the code to make the structure be like that or the last block I wrote in my question?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the full value of `$jsonValues`.